# Scala - Passing values to pattern matchers (Play Framework 2x)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, pattern-matching, playframework-2.1

I'd like to know if there is a way to pass additional values to a pattern matcher. I am using the Play Framework 2.1-RC1 and mysql.

Currently I have a class called **Post** for representing user posts in our web app. A user visits the site, which uses the following method to pull posts from the DB that get beautifully rendered in the browser. This all works fine.

```
case class Post(id:Long, message:String)

object Post extends ObjectModel {
  val simple = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
    get[String]("message") map {
      case id~message=>
        Post(
          id,
          message
        )
    }
  }

  def fetch(): List[Post] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val ret = SQL( "SELECT id, message FROM post" ).as(Post.simple *)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, what'd I'd like to do is add another field to the **Post** class that signifies whether the current user (based on the session) has *starred* a post or not. This requires an additional DB call and ideally I'd like to do something like the following:

```
case class Post(id:Long, message:String, starred:Boolean)

object Post extends ObjectModel {
  val simple = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
    get[String]("message") map {
      case id~message=>
        Post(
          id,
          message,
          didStar(id, userId)
        )
    }
  }
...
```

So my question is how do I get the **userId** value to the pattern matcher. I don't want to pass the data through the database. I can pass the **userId** to the fetch() method, but how do I reference it from within the pattern matcher? Or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Why not to add new column to the `post` table?

Comment: Because there is not a 1-to-1 mapping between posts and users. I need to be able to fetch the same groups of posts for multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know details about your schema, but you could set default value, and update it later:

```
case class Post(id:Long, message:String, starred:Boolean)

object Post extends ObjectModel {
  val simple = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
    get[String]("message") map {
      case id~message => Post(
        id, 
        message,
        starred = false // default value
      )
    }
  }
...
val post = // fetch post
val starred = // determine if post was starred
post.copy(starred = starred) // update value
```

`post.copy` returns new object with the field updated.